# D3 V4 Marker on Arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to build an application with D3 V4 and have the following problem:
I use a d3.forceSimulation and want to visualize circles. These circles can be connected with one or more links.
For drawing the links I use [this](http://bl.ocks.org/thomasdobber/9b78824119136778052f64a967c070e0) example.

But I want to have a marker on each link. For that I use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7HZcR/3/) as example. But in my application I have a bigger radius of the circles, so the `refX` is `70.5`. That causes that my marker doesn't hit the arc anymore and I need to adapt the `refY`-attribute of the marker.

**Screenshot:**

[image: markers dont hit link]

I have tried to calculate the refY with the Pythagorean theorem in the ticked-method:

```
d3.selectAll("marker")
    .attr("refY", function(d){
        var dx = (d.target.x - d.source.x),
            dy = (d.target.y - d.source.y),
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
            unevenCorrection = (d.sameUneven ? 0 : 0.5),
            arc = ((dr * d.maxSameHalf) / (d.sameIndexCorrected - unevenCorrection));
        var hyp = Math.sqrt(refX*refX+arc*arc)
        var offset = hyp - arc;
        if(d.sameMiddleLink)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return d.sameArcDirection === 0? offset:-offset;
        }
    })
;
```

But it still doesn't hit the link.

Can someone help me and show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Stack snippet is for running code only, I just removed it. Also, please provide your simulation, so you can get a working answer.

Comment: See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226734/align-marker-on-node-edges-d3-force-layout/41229068#41229068)

Comment: @Mark thanks alot! Found the solution there.