# d3 v4 add arrows to force-directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a force-directed graph in d3.js with arrows pointing to non-uniform sized nodes. I came across this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226734/align-marker-on-node-edges-d3-force-layout/41229068#41229068) but for the life of me I can't adapt my code to add the arrows in. I'm not sure if I need to be adding something extra to the tick function, or if I'm referencing something incorrectly. Can anyone help me out?

Codepen - https://codepen.io/quirkules/pen/dqXRwj

```
var links_data = [{"source":"ABS","target":"ABS","count":8},{"source":"ABS","target":"ATS","count":1},{"source":"ABS","target":"CR","count":8},{"source":"ABS","target":"ENV","count":1},{"source":"ABS","target":"INT","count":16},{"source":"ABS","target":"ITS","count":9},{"source":"ABS","target":"PDG","count":1},{"source":"ABS","target":"PER","count":4},{"source":"ABS","target":"PRAC","count":3},{"source":"AC","target":"AC","count":1},{"source":"AC","target":"INT","count":9},{"source":"AC","target":"ITS","count":1},{"source":"ACDC","target":"ACDC","count":1},{"source":"ACDC","target":"CR","count":2},{"source":"ACDC","target":"ITS","count":13},{"source":"ACDC","target":"PER","count":4},{"source":"APL","target":"APL","count":8},{"source":"APL","target":"CR","count":3},{"source":"APL","target":"ENV","count":1},{"source":"APL","target":"INT","count":1},{"source":"APL","target":"ITS","count":29},{"source":"APL","target":"LA","count":1},{"source":"APL","target":"PEG","count":1},{"source":"APL","target":"PER","count":3},{"source":"AST","target":"AST","count":17},{"source":"AST","target":"COP","count":1},{"source":"AST","target":"DBT","count":2},{"source":"AST","target":"DEVOPS","count":1},{"source":"AST","target":"IGN","count":1},{"source":"AST","target":"INT","count":2},{"source":"AST","target":"ITS","count":32},{"source":"AST","target":"PDG","count":2},{"source":"AST","target":"PER","count":8},{"source":"ATS","target":"ABS","count":1},{"source":"ATS","target":"ATS","count":21},{"source":"ATS","target":"DBT","count":1},{"source":"ATS","target":"INT","count":3},{"source":"ATS","target":"PDG","count":1},{"source":"ATS","target":"PEG","count":1},{"source":"CAR","target":"APL","count":1},{"source":"CAR","target":"CAR","count":9},{"source":"CAR","target":"COP","count":1},{"source":"CAR","target":"INT","count":9},{"source":"CAR","target":"ITS","count":8},{"source":"IGN","target":"CR","count":4},{"source":"IGN","target":"IGN","count":13},{"source":"IGN","target":"INT","count":5},{"source":"IGN","target":"ITS","count":13},{"source":"IGN","target":"PER","count":4},{"source":"IGN","target":"PRAC","count":1},{"source":"LA","target":"AC","count":1},{"source":"LA","target":"INT","count":1},{"source":"LA","target":"ITS","count":37},{"source":"LA","target":"LA","count":18},{"source":"LA","target":"PER","count":2},{"source":"LOT","target":"LOT","count":18},{"source":"PDG","target":"ABS","count":1},{"source":"PDG","target":"AST","count":4},{"source":"PDG","target":"ATS","count":1},{"source":"PDG","target":"CAR","count":1},{"source":"PDG","target":"CR","count":8},{"source":"PDG","target":"ICS","count":1},{"source":"PDG","target":"IGN","count":3},{"source":"PDG","target":"INT","count":18},{"source":"PDG","target":"ITS","count":6},{"source":"PDG","target":"NRB","count":4},{"source":"PDG","target":"ONT","count":1},{"source":"PDG","target":"PDG","count":24},{"source":"PDG","target":"PER","count":1},{"source":"PEG","target":"CAR","count":1},{"source":"PEG","target":"ENV","count":1},{"source":"PEG","target":"INFRA","count":1},{"source":"PEG","target":"ITS","count":22},{"source":"PEG","target":"LA","count":1},{"source":"PEG","target":"PEG","count":51},{"source":"PEG","target":"PER","count":6},{"source":"RPT","target":"ABS","count":1},{"source":"RPT","target":"APL","count":1},{"source":"RPT","target":"IGN","count":1},{"source":"RPT","target":"INT","count":9},{"source":"RPT","target":"ITS","count":2},{"source":"RPT","target":"RPT","count":11},{"source":"RPT","target":"RTR","count":1},{"source":"RWWA","target":"INT","count":1},{"source":"RWWA","target":"ITS","count":1},{"source":"RWWA","target":"PER","count":1},{"source":"RWWA","target":"RWWA","count":1},{"source":"SCOR","target":"SCOR","count":5},{"source":"SPK","target":"INT","count":4},{"source":"SPK","target":"ITS","count":4},{"source":"SPK","target":"SPK","count":21},{"source":"TS","target":"CS","count":1},{"source":"TS","target":"TS","count":10}];

var nodes_data = [{"name":"ABS","total":11},{"name":"ATS","total":23},{"name":"CR","total":25},{"name":"ENV","total":3},{"name":"INT","total":78},{"name":"ITS","total":177},{"name":"PDG","total":28},{"name":"PER","total":33},{"name":"PRAC","total":4},{"name":"AC","total":2},{"name":"ACDC","total":1},{"name":"APL","total":10},{"name":"LA","total":20},{"name":"PEG","total":53},{"name":"AST","total":21},{"name":"COP","total":2},{"name":"DBT","total":3},{"name":"DEVOPS","total":1},{"name":"IGN","total":18},{"name":"CAR","total":11},{"name":"LOT","total":18},{"name":"ICS","total":1},{"name":"NRB","total":4},{"name":"ONT","total":1},{"name":"INFRA","total":1},{"name":"RPT","total":11},{"name":"RTR","total":1},{"name":"RWWA","total":1},{"name":"SCOR","total":5},{"name":"SPK","total":21},{"name":"CS","total":1},{"name":"TS","total":10}];

   //create node size scale
  var nodeSizeScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(nodes_data, d => d.total))
    .range([30, 70]);

  //create node size scale
  var linkSizeScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(links_data, d => d.count))
    .range([5, 30]);

  //create node size scale
  var linkColourScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(links_data, d => d.count))
    .range(['blue', 'red']);

//document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = '<div>' + JSON.stringify(nodes_data) + '</div>';

//create somewhere to put the force directed graph
var height = 650,
  width = 950;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr('width',width)
      .attr('height',height);

var radius = 15;


//set up the simulation and add forces  
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
          .nodes(nodes_data);

var link_force =  d3.forceLink(links_data)
          .id(function(d) { return d.name; })
          ;

var charge_force = d3.forceManyBody()
    .strength(-1000); 

var center_force = d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2);  

simulation
    .force("charge_force", charge_force)
    .force("center_force", center_force)
    .force("link",link_force)
 ;

//add tick instructions: 
simulation.on("tick", tickActions );

// THIS CODE SECTION ISN'T RENDERING
// Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["dominating"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function (d) {
        return d;
    })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 12)
    .attr("markerHeight", 12)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

//add encompassing group for the zoom 
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "everything");

// add the curved links to our graphic
var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links_data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style('stroke', d => {return linkColourScale(d.count);})
    .attr('stroke-opacity', 0.5)
    .attr('stroke-width', d => {return linkSizeScale(d.count);});

//draw circles for the nodes 
var node = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes") 
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes_data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", d => {return nodeSizeScale(d.total);})
        .attr("fill", "#333")
        .on("mouseover", mouseOver(.1))
        .on("mouseout", mouseOut); 

//add text labels
var text = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes_data)
    .enter().append("text")
    .style("text-anchor","middle")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name });

//add drag capabilities  
var drag_handler = d3.drag()
  .on("start", drag_start)
  .on("drag", drag_drag)
  .on("end", drag_end); 

drag_handler(node);


//add zoom capabilities 
var zoom_handler = d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", zoom_actions);

zoom_handler(svg);     

/** Functions **/

//Drag functions 
//d is the node 
function drag_start(d) {
 if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

//make sure you can't drag the circle outside the box
function drag_drag(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function drag_end(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

//Zoom functions 
function zoom_actions(){
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}

function tickActions() {
    //update circle positions each tick of the simulation 
       node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

    //update link positions 
    link.attr("d", positionLink);

    text.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

// links are drawn as curved paths between nodes,
// through the intermediate nodes
function positionLink(d) {
    var offset = 30;

    var midpoint_x = (d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2;
    var midpoint_y = (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2;

    var dx = (d.target.x - d.source.x);
    var dy = (d.target.y - d.source.y);

    var normalise = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));

    var offSetX = midpoint_x + offset * (dy / normalise);
    var offSetY = midpoint_y - offset * (dx / normalise);

    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y +
        "S" + offSetX + "," + offSetY +
        " " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

// build a dictionary of nodes that are linked
var linkedByIndex = {};
links_data.forEach(function(d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});

// check the dictionary to see if nodes are linked
function isConnected(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index] || a.index == b.index;
}

// fade nodes on hover
function mouseOver(opacity) {
    return function(d) {
        // check all other nodes to see if they're connected
        // to this one. if so, keep the opacity at 1, otherwise
        // fade
        node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
            return thisOpacity;
        });
        node.style("fill-opacity", function(o) {
            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
            return thisOpacity;
        });
        text.style("fill-opacity", function(o) {
            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
            return thisOpacity;
        });
        // also style link accordingly
        link.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
            return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
        });
        link.style("stroke", function(o) {
            return o.source === d || o.target === d ? linkColourScale(o.count) : "#333";
        });
    };
}

function mouseOut() {
    node.style("stroke-opacity", 1);
    node.style("fill-opacity", 1);
    text.style("fill-opacity", 1);
    link.style("stroke-opacity", 0.5);
    link.style("stroke", d => {return linkColourScale(d.count);});
}
```

Comment: where in your code do you set the `marker-end` attribute to the link paths?

Comment: Haven't done that, I'll take a look around at how to achieve that.

Comment: take a look at the example

Comment: Ok, I've managed to append the markers and normalise their size, but now I can't get the arrow to reposition based on the node size. I've tried isolating this as a separate function positionEnd() but it doesn't seem to be working. Have I missed something else? https://codepen.io/quirkules/pen/dqXRwj

Comment: you have to let the path end at the circle edge, with curved paths it complicates the math, use binary search and `path.getPointAtLength(t)`

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused, how would that work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179078/discussion-between-quirk-and-riov8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have applied the same code changes in the example you referred, to your code and it seems to work fine.

The only extra update required was, since you had nodes connecting to itself, I had to apply marker-end property and path length updates only to the filtered set of links.

```js
var links_data = [{"source":"ABS","target":"ABS","count":8},{"source":"ABS","target":"ATS","count":1},{"source":"ABS","target":"CR","count":8},{"source":"ABS","target":"ENV","count":1},{"source":"ABS","target":"INT","count":16},{"source":"ABS","target":"ITS","count":9},{"source":"ABS","target":"PDG","count":1},{"source":"ABS","target":"PER","count":4},{"source":"ABS","target":"PRAC","count":3},{"source":"AC","target":"AC","count":1},{"source":"AC","target":"INT","count":9},{"source":"AC","target":"ITS","count":1},{"source":"ACDC","target":"ACDC","count":1},{"source":"ACDC","target":"CR","count":2},{"source":"ACDC","target":"ITS","count":13},{"source":"ACDC","target":"PER","count":4},{"source":"APL","target":"APL","count":8},{"source":"APL","target":"CR","count":3},{"source":"APL","target":"ENV","count":1},{"source":"APL","target":"INT","count":1},{"source":"APL","target":"ITS","count":29},{"source":"APL","target":"LA","count":1},{"source":"APL","target":"PEG","count":1},{"source":"APL","target":"PER","count":3},{"source":"AST","target":"AST","count":17},{"source":"AST","target":"COP","count":1},{"source":"AST","target":"DBT","count":2},{"source":"AST","target":"DEVOPS","count":1},{"source":"AST","target":"IGN","count":1},{"source":"AST","target":"INT","count":2},{"source":"AST","target":"ITS","count":32},{"source":"AST","target":"PDG","count":2},{"source":"AST","target":"PER","count":8},{"source":"ATS","target":"ABS","count":1},{"source":"ATS","target":"ATS","count":21},{"source":"ATS","target":"DBT","count":1},{"source":"ATS","target":"INT","count":3},{"source":"ATS","target":"PDG","count":1},{"source":"ATS","target":"PEG","count":1},{"source":"CAR","target":"APL","count":1},{"source":"CAR","target":"CAR","count":9},{"source":"CAR","target":"COP","count":1},{"source":"CAR","target":"INT","count":9},{"source":"CAR","target":"ITS","count":8},{"source":"IGN","target":"CR","count":4},{"source":"IGN","target":"IGN","count":13},{"source":"IGN","target":"INT","count":5},{"source":"IGN","target":"ITS","count":13},{"source":"IGN","target":"PER","count":4},{"source":"IGN","target":"PRAC","count":1},{"source":"LA","target":"AC","count":1},{"source":"LA","target":"INT","count":1},{"source":"LA","target":"ITS","count":37},{"source":"LA","target":"LA","count":18},{"source":"LA","target":"PER","count":2},{"source":"LOT","target":"LOT","count":18},{"source":"PDG","target":"ABS","count":1},{"source":"PDG","target":"AST","count":4},{"source":"PDG","target":"ATS","count":1},{"source":"PDG","target":"CAR","count":1},{"source":"PDG","target":"CR","count":8},{"source":"PDG","target":"ICS","count":1},{"source":"PDG","target":"IGN","count":3},{"source":"PDG","target":"INT","count":18},{"source":"PDG","target":"ITS","count":6},{"source":"PDG","target":"NRB","count":4},{"source":"PDG","target":"ONT","count":1},{"source":"PDG","target":"PDG","count":24},{"source":"PDG","target":"PER","count":1},{"source":"PEG","target":"CAR","count":1},{"source":"PEG","target":"ENV","count":1},{"source":"PEG","target":"INFRA","count":1},{"source":"PEG","target":"ITS","count":22},{"source":"PEG","target":"LA","count":1},{"source":"PEG","target":"PEG","count":51},{"source":"PEG","target":"PER","count":6},{"source":"RPT","target":"ABS","count":1},{"source":"RPT","target":"APL","count":1},{"source":"RPT","target":"IGN","count":1},{"source":"RPT","target":"INT","count":9},{"source":"RPT","target":"ITS","count":2},{"source":"RPT","target":"RPT","count":11},{"source":"RPT","target":"RTR","count":1},{"source":"RWWA","target":"INT","count":1},{"source":"RWWA","target":"ITS","count":1},{"source":"RWWA","target":"PER","count":1},{"source":"RWWA","target":"RWWA","count":1},{"source":"SCOR","target":"SCOR","count":5},{"source":"SPK","target":"INT","count":4},{"source":"SPK","target":"ITS","count":4},{"source":"SPK","target":"SPK","count":21},{"source":"TS","target":"CS","count":1},{"source":"TS","target":"TS","count":10}];

var nodes_data = [{"name":"ABS","total":11},{"name":"ATS","total":23},{"name":"CR","total":25},{"name":"ENV","total":3},{"name":"INT","total":78},{"name":"ITS","total":177},{"name":"PDG","total":28},{"name":"PER","total":33},{"name":"PRAC","total":4},{"name":"AC","total":2},{"name":"ACDC","total":1},{"name":"APL","total":10},{"name":"LA","total":20},{"name":"PEG","total":53},{"name":"AST","total":21},{"name":"COP","total":2},{"name":"DBT","total":3},{"name":"DEVOPS","total":1},{"name":"IGN","total":18},{"name":"CAR","total":11},{"name":"LOT","total":18},{"name":"ICS","total":1},{"name":"NRB","total":4},{"name":"ONT","total":1},{"name":"INFRA","total":1},{"name":"RPT","total":11},{"name":"RTR","total":1},{"name":"RWWA","total":1},{"name":"SCOR","total":5},{"name":"SPK","total":21},{"name":"CS","total":1},{"name":"TS","total":10}];

   //create node size scale
  var nodeSizeScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(nodes_data, d => d.total))
    .range([30, 70]);

  //create node size scale
  var linkSizeScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(links_data, d => d.count))
    .range([5, 30]);

  //create node size scale
  var linkColourScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(links_data, d => d.count))
    .range(['blue', 'red']);

//document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = '<div>' + JSON.stringify(nodes_data) + '</div>';

//create somewhere to put the force directed graph
var height = 650,
  width = 950;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr('width',width)
      .attr('height',height);
    
var radius = 15;


//set up the simulation and add forces  
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
          .nodes(nodes_data);
                              
var link_force =  d3.forceLink(links_data)
          .id(function(d) { return d.name; })
          ;
         
var charge_force = d3.forceManyBody()
    .strength(-1000); 
    
var center_force = d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2);  
                      
simulation
    .force("charge_force", charge_force)
    .force("center_force", center_force)
    .force("link",link_force)
 ;
  
//add tick instructions: 
simulation.on("tick", tickActions );

// THIS CODE SECTION ISN'T RENDERING
// Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
 .data(["dominating"])
 .enter().append("marker")
 .attr('markerUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
 .attr("id", function (d) {
  return d;
 })
 .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
 .attr("refX", 0)
 .attr("refY", 0)
 .attr("markerWidth", 12)
 .attr("markerHeight", 12)
 .attr("orient", "auto-start-reverse")
 .append("path")
 .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5")
 .attr("fill", "red");

//add encompassing group for the zoom 
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "everything");

// add the curved links to our graphic
var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links_data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style('stroke', d => {return linkColourScale(d.count);})
    .attr('stroke-opacity', 0.5)
    .attr('stroke-width', d => {return linkSizeScale(d.count);})
   .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
        if(JSON.stringify(d.target) !== JSON.stringify(d.source))
           return "url(#dominating)";
    });

//draw circles for the nodes 
var node = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes") 
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes_data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", d => {return nodeSizeScale(d.total);})
        .attr("fill", "#333")
        .on("mouseover", mouseOver(.1))
        .on("mouseout", mouseOut); 

//add text labels
var text = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes_data)
    .enter().append("text")
    .style("text-anchor","middle")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name });

//add drag capabilities  
var drag_handler = d3.drag()
  .on("start", drag_start)
  .on("drag", drag_drag)
  .on("end", drag_end); 
  
drag_handler(node);


//add zoom capabilities 
var zoom_handler = d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", zoom_actions);

zoom_handler(svg);     

/** Functions **/

//Drag functions 
//d is the node 
function drag_start(d) {
 if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

//make sure you can't drag the circle outside the box
function drag_drag(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function drag_end(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

//Zoom functions 
function zoom_actions(){
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}

function tickActions() {
    //update circle positions each tick of the simulation 
       node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        
    //update link positions 
    link.attr("d", positionLink1);
   link.filter(function(d){ return JSON.stringify(d.target) !== JSON.stringify(d.source); })
      .attr("d",positionLink2);

    text.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
}


function positionLink1(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

  // recalculate and back off the distance
function positionLink2(d) {
     // length of current path
    var pl = this.getTotalLength(),
        // radius of circle plus marker head
        r = nodeSizeScale(d.target.total)+ 12, //12 is the "size" of the marker Math.sqrt(12**2 + 12 **2)
        // position close to where path intercepts circle 
        m = this.getPointAtLength(pl - r);          

     var dx = m.x - d.source.x,
        dy = m.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

      return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + m.x + "," + m.y;
}

// build a dictionary of nodes that are linked
var linkedByIndex = {};
links_data.forEach(function(d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});

// check the dictionary to see if nodes are linked
function isConnected(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index] || a.index == b.index;
}

// fade nodes on hover
function mouseOver(opacity) {
    return function(d) {
        // check all other nodes to see if they're connected
        // to this one. if so, keep the opacity at 1, otherwise
        // fade
        node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
            return thisOpacity;
        });
        node.style("fill-opacity", function(o) {
            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
            return thisOpacity;
        });
        text.style("fill-opacity", function(o) {
            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
            return thisOpacity;
        });
        // also style link accordingly
        link.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
            return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
        });
        link.style("stroke", function(o) {
            return o.source === d || o.target === d ? linkColourScale(o.count) : "#333";
        });
    };
}

function mouseOut() {
    node.style("stroke-opacity", 1);
    node.style("fill-opacity", 1);
    text.style("fill-opacity", 1);
    link.style("stroke-opacity", 0.5);
    link.style("stroke", d => {return linkColourScale(d.count);});
}
```

```css
body {
    width:99%;
    height:100%;
    background: #111111;
}

.svg {
    width:1000;
    height:1000;
}

.link {
 fill: none;
}

.labels {
 font-family: Arial;
 fill: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gilsha, that makes sense! Also thanks for the suggestion around self-referencing links.

Comment: If you look closely the point of the marker is not touching the circle but it overshoots due to the curve of the arc.

Comment: @rioV8 thanks for pointing out. That's a minor fix. There is a place in code where we use static size of the marker. It should have been 12 here. there was a minor change. `nodeSizeScale(d.target.total)+ 12`. Updated in code snippet.