# Using lines with arrows pointing from source to target

Tags: svg, d3.js, d3-force-directed, force-directed-graph

I am trying to convert a D3 force-directed graph codebase.
Source code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/d3js-draggable-force-directed-graph-py3rf

```
var nodes = [
  { color: "red", size: 5 },
  { color: "orange", size: 10 },
  { color: "yellow", size: 15 },
  { color: "green", size: 20 },
  { color: "blue", size: 25 },
  { color: "purple", size: 30 }
];

var links = [
  { source: "red", target: "orange" },
  { source: "orange", target: "yellow" },
  { source: "yellow", target: "green" },
  { source: "green", target: "blue" },
  { source: "blue", target: "purple" },
  { source: "purple", target: "red" },
  { source: "green", target: "red" }
];

var svg = d3
  .select("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var linkSelection = svg
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1);

var nodeSelection = svg
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", d => d.size)
  .attr("fill", d => d.color)
  .call(
    d3
      .drag()
      .on("start", dragStart)
      .on("drag", drag)
      .on("end", dragEnd)
  );
```

the current product looks like this:

[image]

And the snippet is here:

```js
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

var width = 600;
var height = 600;

var nodes = [
  { color: "red", size: 5 },
  { color: "orange", size: 10 },
  { color: "yellow", size: 15 },
  { color: "green", size: 20 },
  { color: "blue", size: 25 },
  { color: "purple", size: 30 }
];

var links = [
  { source: "red", target: "orange" },
  { source: "orange", target: "yellow" },
  { source: "yellow", target: "green" },
  { source: "green", target: "blue" },
  { source: "blue", target: "purple" },
  { source: "purple", target: "red" },
  { source: "green", target: "red" }
];

var svg = d3
  .select("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var linkSelection = svg
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1);

var nodeSelection = svg
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", d => d.size)
  .attr("fill", d => d.color)
  .call(
    d3
      .drag()
      .on("start", dragStart)
      .on("drag", drag)
      .on("end", dragEnd)
  );

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes);

simulation
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("nodes", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force(
    "links",
    d3
      .forceLink(links)
      .id(d => d.color)
      .distance(d => 5 * (d.source.size + d.target.size))
  )
  .on("tick", ticked);

function ticked() {
  // console.log(simulation.alpha());

  nodeSelection.attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);

  linkSelection
    .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
    .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
    .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
    .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
}

function dragStart(d) {
  // console.log('drag start');
  simulation.alphaTarget(0.5).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function drag(d) {
  // console.log('dragging');
  // simulation.alpha(0.5).restart()
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragEnd(d) {
  // console.log('drag end');
  simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg
  version="1.1"
  baseProfile="full"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
></svg>
```

But my goal is draw lines with arrows on the end, where the arrows are pointing to a target from a source. Does anyone know how to properly change the line type, and have it point the right way?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a marker representing the arrow tip in your svg, then use it in a marker-end attribute on your lines.

Here is an example: http://thenewcode.com/1068/Making-Arrows-in-SVG

Answer (score 1):

There is a reasonable solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226734/align-marker-on-node-edges-d3-force-layout?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it is D3 v3 and uses a `path` not `line`.

Basically, using a `marker` you calculate the amount to shorten your `line` so that it starts at the boundary of the `source` node (i.e. shorten by the `source` radius) and ends at the boundary of the `target` node (i.e. shorten at the end by the radius of the `target` node plus the dimension of the marker).

The hard-coded `12` in the snippet is the dimension of the marker - if you change e.g. `markerWidth` then you will probably need to play with this constant in the `tick` function.

So, there are 3 edits to your original code: add the `marker`, append the `marker` to the `line` and in `tick`, do the math to shorten each end and replot the `line`. See below:

```js
var width = 600;
var height = 200;

var nodes = [
  { color: "red", size: 5 },
  { color: "orange", size: 10 },
  { color: "yellow", size: 15 },
  { color: "green", size: 20 },
  { color: "blue", size: 25 },
  { color: "purple", size: 30 }
];

var links = [
  { source: "red", target: "orange" },
  { source: "orange", target: "yellow" },
  { source: "yellow", target: "green" },
  { source: "green", target: "blue" },
  { source: "blue", target: "purple" },
  { source: "purple", target: "red" },
  { source: "green", target: "red" }
];

var svg = d3
  .select("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

// append a path marker to svg defs 
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
  .data(["dominating"])
  .enter().append("marker")
  .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
  .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
  .attr("refX", 0)
  .attr("refY", 0)
  .attr("markerWidth", 12)
  .attr("markerHeight", 12)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
//

var linkSelection = svg
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  // add marker to line
  .attr("marker-end", d => "url(#dominating)");
  //

var nodeSelection = svg
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", d => d.size)
  .attr("fill", d => d.color)
  .call(
    d3
      .drag()
      .on("start", dragStart)
      .on("drag", drag)
      .on("end", dragEnd)
  );

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes);

simulation
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("nodes", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force(
    "links",
    d3
      .forceLink(links)
      .id(d => d.color)
      .distance(d => 5 * (d.source.size + d.target.size))
  )
  .on("tick", ticked);

function ticked() {
  // console.log(simulation.alpha());

  nodeSelection.attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);

  linkSelection
    .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
    .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
    .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
    .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);


  // recalculate and back off the distance
  linkSelection.each(function(d, i, n) {
    // current path length
    const pl = this.getTotalLength();
    // radius of marker head plus def constant
    const mrs = (d.source.size);
    const mrt = (d.target.size) + 12;
    // get new start and end points
    const m1 = this.getPointAtLength(mrs);
    const m2 = this.getPointAtLength(pl - mrt);
    // new line start and end
    d3.select(n[i])
     .attr("x1", m1.x)
     .attr("y1", m1.y)
     .attr("x2", m2.x)
     .attr("y2", m2.y);
  });    
}

function dragStart(d) {
  // console.log('drag start');
  simulation.alphaTarget(0.5).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function drag(d) {
  // console.log('dragging');
  // simulation.alpha(0.5).restart()
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragEnd(d) {
  // console.log('drag end');
  simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg
  version="1.1"
  baseProfile="full"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
></svg>
```

This works on v4.13 and v5.7.

Comment: PS like postscript? I didn't know D3 went to version 7.6.1?

Comment: Yes postscript (changed it though). 7.6.1 is around the latest version.

Comment: are you available for hire with D3? I am looking for someone for about 5 hours of work. Also, your solutions works with v4 and v5, but there's an error with v6 and v7, I get an error here:


`function drag(d) {
            d.fx = d3.event.x;  // <--- can't read prop x of undefined
            d.fy = d3.event.y;
        }`

Comment: I fixed that using this migration guide: https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide